# Error in MySQL syntax when save button is clicked

Tags: mysql, vb.net, save

I'm having a problem while saving data into my database. I am using a MySQL database with database name as time management. When I click save, I get an error at line 1 where it's prompting me to check if the MySQL syntax to use near my table (`datetimepicker1,payroll_no,name,time_in,time_out,time_out,losttime,reason`) is right.
Here is my code

```
Private Sub btnsave_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnsave.Click
    mysqlconn = New MySqlConnection
    mysqlconn.ConnectionString = "server=127.0.0.1;userid=root;" +
"password=;database=time management;"

    Dim command As New MySqlCommand

    If DateTimePicker1.Text = "" Or txtpayroll_no.Text = "" Or txtname.Text = "" Or txttime_in.Text = "" Or txttime_out.Text = "" Or txttime.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Provide All Details")
    Else
        Try
            mysqlconn.Open()
            command.Connection = mysqlconn
            command.CommandText = "INSERT into table(datetimepicker1,payroll_no,name,time_in,time_out,time_out,losttime,reason) VALUE ('" & DateTimePicker1.Text & "','" & txtpayroll_no.Text & "','" & txtname.Text & "','" & txttime_in.Text & "','" & txttime_out.Text & "','" & txttime.Text & "','" & cboreason.Text & "',)"

            command.ExecuteNonQuery()
            MsgBox("SAVED!!")
            DateTimePicker1.Text = ""
            txtpayroll_no.Text = ""
            txtname.Text = ""
            txttime_in.Text = ""
            txttime_out.Text = ""
            txttime.Text = ""
            txttime.Text = ""
            cboreason.Text = ""
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)

        End Try
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: There's a comma at the end of your VALUES list.

Comment: these kinds of errors are almost impossible using SQL params: how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work

Comment: Just to cover the bases... I know it's not, but in your production code you have an actual table name for `INSERT INTO table...`, right? Besides that and the stray comma at the end of your list of values, everything looks correct.

Comment: yep, i have atable and named it table, so what should i change in my code to be able to save data in my db,

Comment: and if i want to calculate lost hours so that when i input time in and time out, the results automatically shows on textbox, there is one hour break from 1.00 to 2.00pm